# Count consecutive days

Tags: sql, sqlite

Please I want to count total consecutive days for an event record and order by this record grouping by actor id . for instance we have. For sqlite

```
event_id| created_at |actor_id
1       |  2018-07-01|  40     /* this is a consecutive days
1       |  2018-07-02|  40     */
1       |  2018-07-04|  40
1       |  2018-07-05|  40
1       |  2018-07-09|  40
2       |  2018-07-11|  40
2       |  2018-07-12|  40
1       |  2018-07-13| 41
```

should give me something like

```
actor_id|streak
40     | 3 
41     | 0
```

Comment: Can you explain: `1, 40, 3`?

Comment: 1 is the event id 40 is the actor id the new record groups by actor_id and counts total events consecutive days gives a streak value 3

Comment: For eventid = 1 there are not 3 consecutive days.

Comment: there are three pairs

Comment: its the pairs am counting not the individual items

Comment: For actor_id = 40 there are 3 consecutive pairs but not for event_id = 1

Comment: am only interested in actor_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group by actor_id` and sum conditionally if there exists a consecutive day:

```
select 
  t.actor_id,
  sum(case when exists (
      select 1 from tablename
      where
        actor_id = t.actor_id and
        julianday(created_at) - julianday(t.created_at) = 1 
  ) then 1 else 0 end) streak
from tablename t
group by t.actor_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2MpDAbKYxhhNQ1PrgUfHQ5/0).
Or with a self join:

```
select 
  t.actor_id,
  sum(tt.created_at is not null) streak
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on tt.actor_id = t.actor_id and julianday(tt.created_at) - julianday(t.created_at) = 1
group by t.actor_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2MpDAbKYxhhNQ1PrgUfHQ5/1).

Results:

```
| actor_id | streak |
| -------- | ------ |
| 40       | 3      |
| 41       | 0      |
```

Comment: Thanks will try it out